# sprintf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, printf

How can I display the value of a variable inside the `sprintf` function in MATLAB? For example, I need to display

> This variable has the type `char` and the value `'whatever'`.

My code looks like this so far:

```
function [desInput] = varInfo (numVec)  

cLass = class(numVec);  
var1 = num2str(numVec);  
desInput = sprintf('This variable is of class %s and has a value of ''%d''.', cLass, var1);       

end
```

It isn't quite working right.

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) **generates** a string of a desired formatting and places it into a variable. If you want to display it, either use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), or use `disp(desInput);` on your created string when using `sprintf`.

Also, you want to display the value `numVec`, but you are converting it to a string before display.  As such, either remove the `num2str` call, or use `%s` as the modifier when displaying your number.

Therefore, do either this:

```
function [desInput] = varInfo (numVec)

cLass = class(numVec);
desInput = sprintf('This variable is of class %s and has a value of ''%d''.', cLass, numVec);
disp(desInput);

end
```

OR

```
function [desInput] = varInfo (numVec)

cLass = class(numVec);
fprintf('This variable is of class %s and has a value of ''%d''.\n', cLass, numVec);

end
```

OR

```
function [desInput] = varInfo (numVec)

cLass = class(numVec);
var1 = num2str(numVec);
desInput = sprintf('This variable is of class %s and has a value of ''%s''.', cLass, var1);
disp(desInput);

end
```

OR

```
function [desInput] = varInfo (numVec)

cLass = class(numVec);
var1 = num2str(numVec);
fprintf('This variable is of class %s and has a value of ''%s''.\n', cLass, var1);
disp(desInput);

end
```

Notice that in the `fprintf` solution, I insert a newline so that the command prompt `>>` goes underneath your text when displayed.

Comment: This is the output I get for what you suggested in the fprintf suggestion: This variable is of class char and has a value of '73'.This variable is of class  love MATLAB!! and has a value of '
info1 =

   116                                                 when I do the first thing I get this:  This variable is of class char and has a value of '73'.This variable is of class  love MATLAB!! and has a value of '

Comment: Aha, yeah your `sprintf` statement isn't correct either.  You are converting your number into a string.  I'll modify.  I didn't see that there to begin with.

Comment: @JudithNelson-Spanks - Modified.

Comment: @JudithNelson-Spanks - My pleasure :) The usual action is to accept the answer that helped you.  No pressure, but that would be awesome :).  Click on the checkmark icon that is beside my answer at the top, and to the left.

Answer (score 0):

`num2str` produces a string representation. You should use `%s` for it as well.

To see the difference:

```
N = 65; % random example
fprintf('%d\n', num2str(N)); % produces 5453
fprintf('%s\n', num2str(N)); % produces 65
```